# How to add popup Modal in scandipwa?

Tags: popup, pwa, modal, react

I want to create popup modal in scandi. Code is tried is s follows-

> Popup.js

```
import React from "react";
 
const Popup = props => {
  return (
    <div className="popup-box">
      <div className="box">
        <span className="close-icon" onClick={props.handleClose}>x</span>
        {props.content}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

> Popupcomponent.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Popup from './Popup';
import  './style.css';
 
function PopupComponent() {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
 
  const togglePopup = () => {
    setIsOpen(!isOpen);
  }
 
  return <div>
    <input
      type="button"
      value="Click to Open Popup"
      onClick={togglePopup}
    />
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    {isOpen && <Popup
      content={<>
        <b>Design your Popup</b>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p><br/>
        <button>Test button</button> 
      </>}
      handleClose={togglePopup}
    />}
  </div>
}
 
export default PopupComponent;
```

This is working fine in react but in Scandi, getting errorwhile using `useState`

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className=""App"">
      <h1>Create React Modal in X line of code </h1>
      <button>Click Me</button>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById(""root"");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);

import React from ""react"";
import ReactDOM from ""react-dom"";
import Popup from ""reactjs-popup"";

import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Create React Modal with 22 line of code </h1>
      <Popup modal trigger={<button>Click Me</button>}>
        Modal Content
      </Popup>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```